How can I automate Python package installation from Google Artifact Registry without needing to log in every time?
I'm working on a airflow that requires installing Python packages from Google Artifact Registry. I want to configure my development environment so that these packages can be installed without the need for repeated authentication, as the project is shared among multiple developers

I’m using Google Cloud SDK to manage my packages.
I have created a service account with the necessary permissions and downloaded the JSON key.
I can authenticate using the following command:

gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=PATH_TO_YOUR_JSON_KEY
